# Aws enable unnecessary TLS protocol versions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

When I turn on debug mode I noticed that Amazon S3 Client use protocols versions I do now want to:

[image: Example]

And than I found out that it does not matter for AWS what protocol I want to use (see SdkTLSSocketFactory)

[image: SdkTLSSocketFactory]

Does I really can't to say AWS what protocol version to use?